# SQL Tracking the latest record and update

Tags: sql, hive, apache-pig, apache-spark-sql

I have a table id_track history, which is updating id in different time-stamp. I want to consolidate into latest id by iterative search in sql. How can I do it in SQL?

Table:

`OLD_ID  NEW_ID  TIME-STAMP
101 103 1/5/2001
102 108 2/5/2001
103 105 3/5/2001
105 106 4/5/2001
110 111 4/5/2001
108 116 14/5/2001
112 117 4/6/2001
104 118 4/7/2001
111 119 4/8/2001`

Desired Resulting table:

`OLD_ID  LATEST_ID   LAST TIME-STAMP
101 106 4/5/2001
102 116 14/5/2001
104 118 4/7/2001
110 111 4/5/2001
112 117 4/6/2001
111 119 4/8/2001`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa5tQ.jpg)

Comment: stackoveflow is not a free coding service. You must try to resolve the problem yourself first; then if stuck ask for specific help. What query have you tried? Also you have not attempted to explain how `old_id` 101 gets coupled to `new_id` 106. There is no apparent logical reason for that. In the image you are using colors - do they mean something? what?

Comment: In the table old_id 101 have new value 103, then 103 changes to 105, 105 changes to 106. so 101 will have latest id 106. It can be done by correlated sql search.

Comment: There is something that you know about this data that you are not explaining. There has to be something else that makes 101 relate to 106... you are not explaining what that is.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT old_id,
         (    SELECT MAX (new_id)
                FROM test01 b
          START WITH old_id = a.old_id
          CONNECT BY old_id = PRIOR new_id)
            new_id,
         (SELECT time_stamp
            FROM test01 c
           WHERE new_id = (    SELECT MAX (new_id)
                                 FROM test01 b
                           START WITH old_id = a.old_id
                           CONNECT BY old_id = PRIOR new_id))
            time_stamp
    FROM test01 a
   WHERE old_id NOT IN (SELECT new_id
                          FROM test01 c)
ORDER BY old_id ASC;

where test01 is the table having data. We have to use START WITH .. CONNECT BY PRIOR